# Image is not uploading to server using Laravel API while working with core PHP API

Tags: php, android, laravel, android-volley

I'm uploading image using Volley library using webservices written Laravel. Android code is: it shows 500 internal server error

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button buttonChoose;
    private Button buttonUpload;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private EditText editTextName;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private String UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.1.9/volley/upload.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonChoose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
        editTextName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        //Showing the progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                //Disimissing the progress dialog
                loading.dismiss();
                //Showing toast message of the response
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, KEY_IMAGE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                //Dismissing the progress dialog
                loading.dismiss();

                //Showing toast
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Converting Bitmap to String
            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

            //Getting Image Name
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating parameters
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            //Adding parameters
            params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
            params.put(KEY_NAME, name);

            //returning parameters
            return params;
        }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            showFileChooser();
        }

        if (v == buttonUpload) {
            uploadImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Laravel API code is

```
$filename = Input::get('name');
$imageStr = $request->input('image');
$decodeImage = base64_decode($imageStr);
//        $image = fwrite($decodeImage);
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $filename = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $moveImage = $request->file('image')->move('uploads/images', $filename);
}
$image = new Image();
$image->photo = "uploads/images/".$filename;
$image->name = Input::get('name');
$result = $image->save();
if ($result){
    return response()->json('yes');
}
else{
    return response()->json('no');
}
```

But when I uses core PHP API image is uploaded successfully.
Kindly help to find problem, core PHP code is:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM volley ORDER BY id ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $id = 2;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
    }

    $path = "uploads/$name.png";

    $actualpath = "http://192.168.2.113/volley/$path";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO image (photo,name) VALUES ('$actualpath','$name')";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($image));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $filename = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $moveImage = $request->file('image')->move('uploads/images', $filename);
}
```

because you are checking if request is contain file or not and your are sending base64 encodeed data which is not file so your file is not uploading

here this is working code

```
$filename = Input::get('name');
$imageStr = $request->input('image');

if (!empty($imageStr)) {
    file_put_contents('YOUR_UPLOAD_PATH/'.$filename.'.png', base64_decode($imageStr));
}
$image = new Image();
$image->photo = "YOUR_UPLOAD_PATH/".$filename.'.png';
$image->name = $filename.'.png';
$result = $image->save();
if ($result){
    return response()->json('yes');
}
else{
    return response()->json('no');
}
```